# Reload app on custom file change in playframework

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.0

In playframework there is auto-reload feature. It means that in development mode on each request play checks files on changes, and recompiles and reloads project if necessary. So, for example if I `$ touch conf/routes`, project will be reloaded on next request.

I'd like to add some custom file to watch for.

I believe [`watchSources`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala#L111) setting contains list of files play is watching for. But it doesn't work for me. Consider, we want to add `trigger` file to watched sources.

```
watchSources <+= baseDirectory map { _ / "trigger" }
```

It is successfully added to watch sources

```
[sbt console] $ show watch-sources
[info] List(/* trigger appears in list */)
```

But play ignores `trigger` changes and doesn't restart application. What I am missing? How to make play watch for custom file changes?

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question, but did you remember to do a `play reload` after editing Build.scala?

Comment: Tried to clean, reload, move to 2.1-SNAPSHOT. I started to think all watched files are hardcoded somewhere in [PlayReloader](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayReloader.scala)

Comment: The sbt documention is talking about the `watch` setting: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Triggered-Execution. But I can't any find more information about that setting in the wiki.

Comment: @Li-o, `watch-sources` works well for plain `sbt` project, but play relies on its own fancy `PlayReloader`, overriding standard behavior.

Comment: @4e6, if you add a file to `watchSources` and execute the `~run` command it does detect changes on that file. This seems to be explicitly coded in the `PlayLoader`: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala#L693

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do this, but after investigating, I noticed that

```
watchSources <+= confDirectory map { _ / "routes" }
```

naturally points to the routes file in conf (conf/routes). Is it possible you forgot to put the file "trigger" in conf (conf/trigger)?

Comment: I suspect auto-reload will work for every file in `conf` directory even not listed in `watchSources` because of these lines in [PlayReloader](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayReloader.scala#L21)